# Why are there updates for relatively stable programs like Vim, zip, tar or xxd?

Tags: linux, apt, repository, software-updates

After I do an apt update, there are updates to packages like vim, tar or xxd. Since these are relatively stable, why do they have frequent updates?

Comment: New versions have most likely been released so new binaries.

Comment: Why not post the theory of `vim` being *relatively stable* in a *neovim* forum? But wait for me to get some popcorn first! (-;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which distribution are you looking at? If it is a distribution that relies on packages from Debian's `unstable`, you might be getting every minor bug fix, feature addition and other tweak as a separate update.

As others mentioned, `vim` and `xxd` both come from the same source code package.
So here are the three most recent entries from the change log of the `vim` source code package in Debian unstable:

```
vim (2:8.2.4793-1) unstable; urgency=medium

  * Merge upstream patch v8.2.4793

 -- James McCoy <jamessan@debian.org>  Wed, 20 Apr 2022 20:23:54 -0400

vim (2:8.2.4659-1) unstable; urgency=medium

  * Merge upstream patch v8.2.4659
    + 8.2.4151: reading beyond end of a line (Closes: #1004859, CVE-2022-0318)
    + autoload/phpcomplete.vim: Fix E565 error in omni-completion (Closes:
      #1008710)
  * Remove outdated NEWS and README.Debian entries
  * README.Debian: Fix links to vim-policy
  * Improve docs about purpose and effect of defaults.vim (Closes: #856273)
  * Define system (g)vimrc location as /etc/vim/(g)vimrc, rather than
    symlinking from /usr/share/vim/(g)vimrc -> /etc/vim/(g)vimrc.
  * Replace vim-athena with vim-motif, Athena GUI deprecated upstream
  * Remove lintian override for rgb.txt, removed upstream
  * Declare compliance with Policy 4.6.0, no changes needed
  * Remove vim-gtk transitional package

 -- James McCoy <jamessan@debian.org>  Sun, 03 Apr 2022 10:44:13 -0400

vim (2:8.2.3995-1) unstable; urgency=medium

  * Merge upstream patch v8.2.3918
    + 8.2.3610: crash when ModeChanged triggered too early (Closes: #1001900,
      CVE-2021-3968)
    + 8.2.3611: crash when using CTRL-W f without finding a file name (Closes:
      #1001899, CVE-2021-3973)
    + 8.2.3612: using freed memory with regexp using a mark (Closes: #1001897,
      CVE-2021-3974)
    + 8.2.3625: illegal memory access when C-indenting (Closes: #1001896,
      CVE-2021-3984)
    + 8.2.3847: illegal memory access when using a lambda with an error
      (Closes: #1002534, CVE-2021-4136)
    + autoload/zip.vim: Use URI syntax for pseudo-filename to avoid empty
      buffer after 8.2.3468 (Closes: #1000767)
  * Revert "Disable Test_very_large_count since it fails on 32-bit systems",
    fixed upstream

 -- James McCoy <jamessan@debian.org>  Mon, 03 Jan 2022 17:57:10 -0500
```

Likewise for `tar`:

```
tar (1.34+dfsg-1) unstable; urgency=medium

  * New upstream version

 -- Janos Lenart <ocsi@debian.org>  Wed, 17 Feb 2021 09:55:26 +0000

tar (1.33+dfsg-1) unstable; urgency=medium

  * New upstream version
  * Removed unsafe escaping from mailcap-entry; closes: #982614
  * Fixed trailing whitespaces in debian/{changelog,control,rules}

 -- Janos Lenart <ocsi@debian.org>  Fri, 12 Feb 2021 15:15:21 +0000

tar (1.32+dfsg-1) unstable; urgency=medium

  * New upstream version; closes: #892273
  * Huge thanks to Bdale for maintaining tar since 1995; closes: #973844

 -- Janos Lenart <ocsi@debian.org>  Fri, 20 Nov 2020 09:52:51 +0000
```

You can find Debian's package-specific changelogs pretty easily: go to `https://packages.debian.org/unstable/<package name>` and you'll get a page of package details. Then go to the right sidebar and select "Debian Changelog" from there.

If you do this for the `xxd` package, you'll see the package details for `xxd` as usual, but the "Debian Changelog" link on that page will automatically direct you to the changelog of the `vim` source code package, since that's the source used to build both `xxd` and `vim` binary packages.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't actually much about UNIX/Linux, but about software updates in general!

1. `xxd` is actually a program from the vim tooling, so chances are something inherent to both has updated
2. `vim` is not *that* stable – it's a medium- to large-sized code base and there's always going to be bugs to fix. And people want features, and people want `vim` to work on say Ubuntu 22.10, so that necessitates a lot of work. If you [look at the git history of vim](https://github.com/vim/vim/commits/master) you'll find that on average, more than 5 changes per day make it into vim's source. So, yeah: There's going to be updates.
3. Even if there weren't any bugs in software to fix, software depends on other software to do some functionality. For example, not every program that can read data through HTTP wants to implement HTTP itself (and not only waste time implementing a large and complex standard with thousands of servers that might or might not be 100% compliant), but uses *libraries* to do that. Sometimes, when such a library gets updated, software using that library has to be recompiled. And that forces the maintainers to send an update for all the software depending on a library if that library gets updated. (Library authors and maintainers try to avoid that!)

Comment: +1 indeed for the major reasons. Adding one : When upstream don't publish packages leading distro's dev to package from git (think of qtwebengine for ex.) each distro will have its own policy to update their package every x days irrespective of the amount of changes made upstream.

Comment: @MC68020 not quite that easy: non-rolling-release distros will not generally update packages in already released versions of  the distro, unless that update fixes an important security issue or an unavailability of core functionality (e.g. if vim won't start). So, if you see an update of vim in debian bullseye, then that means a maintainer has sat down and specifically made sure to release something that changes as little as possible whilst still fixing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't particularly know about frequent, which is a bit subjective… but even if the feature scope of a tool is fairly fixed, there can be bugs, and even if there are no bugs in the stricter sense, there can be typos in the man pages and things like that.

`vim` is a fairly large, flexible and extensible piece of software under active development, so both feature and bugfix updates happen.

`tar`… well, at the very least, it occasionally gets support for new compression formats, which require new command line switches. And also, file systems have become so complex in terms of file metadata that there's a possibility of unexpected behaviour or feature requests. (I vaguely remember when many years back, almost all tools spawned a `-Z` option to handle SELinux labels, stuff like that.)